# Can I arrange labels of legend in Doughnut chart one by one?

Tags: chart.js, legend

I am using Doughnut chart of chart.js in a react js application. I would need the same look and feel for the legend than illustrated by:.

[image: Doughnut Legend]

I have gone through the Chart.js documentation but I am helpless!

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried.

Comment: labels: {
            boxWidth: 15,
            padding: 10,
            itemMaxWidth: 50
        }

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this at options, see next:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
            boxWidth: 10
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration here you can see all options what you can add to labels, see padding also, default is 10 you need only add boxWidth.

Comment: Hi Alien, thank you for response. But I need the arrangement of labels like in the given image... one after one. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, sorry, misunderstanding. There is no way in options to do that :( only options what you can add,you can see in link. There is also option to add some custom legends like https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends. 
For my chart, I've put it under div with `text-center` class and I've labels one by one.

Comment: Thank you for getting back!! :)